# Kendo UI Date Range Picker mobile handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, kendo-ui

i try to use kendo Date Range Picker with template and it works fine on chrome browser desktop version but i get an error on mobile.

this is the error.

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

and i am trying to solve it with this code but it does not working yet

```
$('body').on("touchstart", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `preventDefault()` on `touchstart` event, probably you should add CSS rule to disable browser handling for gestures like this:

```
.body { 
    touch-action: none; 
}
```

Note that this setting stops any touch scrolling, if you wish to enable standard gestures then `touch-action: manipulation` should be used:

```
.body { 
    touch-action: manipulation; 
}
```

You can see all `touch-action` options in [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action), with a little explanation regarding `preventDefault()` function usage:

> Applications using Touch_events disable the browser handling of
>   gestures by calling `preventDefault()`, but should also use `touch-action`
>   to ensure the browser knows the intent of the application before any
>   event listeners have been invoked.

Additional reference: [Making touch scrolling fast by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention)